# Traverse array and return child nodes on same level

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
rgInventory": {

"2085630349": {
    "id": "2085630349",
    "classid": "253266389",
    "instanceid": "253354499",
    "amount": "1",
    "pos": 1
},
"1938126110": {
    "id": "1938126110",
    "classid": "57939745",
    "instanceid": "0",
    "amount": "1",
    "pos": 2
}, 
...
```

I need to be able to identify which child of rgInventory has the property pos = 1, and then return the id of this child array (in the example above, this would be 2085630349.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any arrays there.

Comment: Read more about [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in) loops, and then try to solve it on your own. If your attempts fail, return and ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not an array, just an object.

You can loop through the keys of an object using a `for-in` loop, like this:

```
var key;
for (key in obj) {
    // `key` will be each key, in no particular order
}
```

It loops not only through the object's own properties, but through enumerable properties it inherits from its prototype. Simple objects like the one you have there don't inherit any enumerable properties from their prototype (unless someone does something really silly, below), but if you wanted to be sure, you could use `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` in the loop above to only handle its own and not inherited ones.

Then just look at `obj[key]`, which is a reference to the child object, and see if it has the relevant `pos` property.

---

Just for completeness, the really silly thing would be this:

```
Object.prototype.someName = /* some value */;
```

...which would create an enumerable property on the prototype used for simple objects. This should **never** be done.